# SQL query does not return anything with this HAVING clause

Tags: sql, having

I want to have all Customer IDs which are higher than the average value of all IDs

```
SELECT k_vorname, k_nachname, k_ID FROM kunden GROUP BY k_ID HAVING k_ID > AVG(k_ID)
```

But this query returns nothing. Why?

Comment: It returns nothing because having clause works only on aggregated values.

Comment: @Grevak . . . It should generate a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below

```
SELECT k_vorname, k_nachname, k_ID FROM kunden 
where k_id > (select AVG(k_ID) from kunden)
```